# Javascript flood-fill function working only partially [Minesweeper]

Tags: javascript, jquery, flood-fill, minesweeper

I've been trying to create my own minesweeper-game (for fun) for a couple months now. Only thing that I have really been stopped by is how to make recursive function (flood-fill) to fill the blank areas in the game.

The flood-fill works only partially. It does not extend to right or the bottom node from any clicked node.

[Current full code](https://jsfiddle.net/60wtx4zz/)

FloodFill -part:

```
function floodFill(node) {

    if (node < 0) {return};

    if (document.getElementById("cell" + node).style.backgroundColor == "white") {return};

    if (document.getElementById("cell" + node).classList.contains("nearby")) {return};

    document.getElementById("cell" + node).style.backgroundColor = "white";

    floodFill(node -= 1);                           
    floodFill(node += 1);
    floodFill(node -= 16);
    floodFill(node += 16);

    return

};

floodFill(here);
```

The "here" means the clicked node. The size of the grid is 16, so the bottom node is current node + 16.

This small game -project means a lot for me, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i have the same problem. i still couldn't solve it. Thx for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators `-=` and `+=` mean subtract/add a certain value to the variable.

```
a += 10;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a + 10;
```

Therefore, in your code

```
floodFill(node -= 1);                           
floodFill(node += 1);
floodFill(node -= 16);
floodFill(node += 16);
```

`node` is being changed on each function call.

If `node` was, for example, 10, the following would happen:

- `node` would be decremented by 1 (`node -= 1`) and is now 9
- `floodFill` would be called, with `node == 9`
- `node` would be incremented by 1 (`node += 1`) and is now 10
- etc.

Instead of assignment operators (`-=`/`+=`), use the normal operators (`-`/`+`) instead.

---

**Solution**: change

```
floodFill(node -= 1);                           
floodFill(node += 1);
floodFill(node -= 16);
floodFill(node += 16);
```

to

```
floodFill(node - 1);                           
floodFill(node + 1);
floodFill(node - 16);
floodFill(node + 16);
```

Hope this helps!